# Vector Width on OSX Implementation of OpenCL on the Intel Iris Graphics 6100 (MBP 2015)

Tags: c++, macos, vector, opencl, gpgpu

[According to Wikipedia, the Iris Graphics 6100 has 48 execution units (EU) with each having a pair of 128 bit FPUs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Eighth_generation) So each EU should support a vector of 8 floating point types. When the device was polled for the preferred vector widths for the GPU, every type comes up as 1, except the double. That came out to be 0. That's expected behavior as doubles aren't supported. The CPU returned all the information correctly. All 48 GPU EUs are recognized as being present as well.

Is this just a bug with the Apple implementation of clGetDeviceInfo? It should at least output that the the preferred width of char vector is bigger than the int vector. But they are all returning 1.

The driver is the latest version (Aug 29, 2016).

edit:

```
clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT, sizeof(maxWidth), &maxWidth, NULL);
```

And

```
clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT, sizeof(maxWidth), &maxWidth, NULL);
```

Both return 1 for all types on the GPU.

CPU returns 16, 8, 4 for Char, Short, Int/Float all respectfully.

Comment: What do your calls to clGetDeviceInfo look like?

Comment: clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT, sizeof(maxWidth), &maxWidth, NULL);

Comment: I think this is idiosyncratic behaviour from Apple's implementation; none of the Mac hardware I've polled in this way (admittedly, not a representative sample) has returned anything other than 1 for vector width. But then Apple's implementation has far worse bugs than this in my experience…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Intel GEN Graphics, the preferred vector width for float vectors is 4, as in float4. For some kernels, float8 sometimes makes sense. So I think this is an issue with the MacOSX driver.